# $L^\infty([0,1])$ is dual space of space of Radon measure

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, dual-spaces

In the lecture [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gr68HmbQza8&list=PLo4jXE-LdDTTIIIRwqK35CbFJieSJEcVR&index=31) (at 16:14s), he claims that the (continuous) dual space of space of Radon measures on $\Omega=[0,1]$ is $L^\infty(\Omega)$. So, I am wondering

1. Where I can cite such results?
2. Do we have similar result for (locally) compact set $\Omega$?

Answer (score 1):

I think the instructor made a mistake there.  It is not even true that $L^\infty(\Omega)$ is contained in the dual of the space $X$ of Radon measures (at least not in a natural way): for instance, it is impossible  to define
$$
  \int_\Omega f\,d\mu,
  $$
for $f\in L^\infty(\Omega)$, in case, say, $\mu=\delta_x$ is the Dirac measure supported on $x$, since $f(x)$ is not well defined.

If you replace $L^\infty(\Omega)$ by the space $B(\Omega)$ of bounded measurable functions on $\Omega$ (**not** moding out when functions agree a.e.) then at least you may embedd
$$B(\Omega) \hookrightarrow X'$$
and I think this is what the instructor had in mind.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response and clarification.